# mapping with automapper missing properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm facing a issue with mapping my objects to the view and back to the original object with automapper.

I have following structure.

```
public class TModel
{
  public int TID{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Location{get;set;} 
  public string address{get;set;} 
}
public class UiModel
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public string Location{get;set;} 
}
```

in the class AutoMapperConfiguration i have a initialize of my automapper like following:

```
cfg.CreateMap < TModel, UiModel  >();
cfg.CreateMap < UiModel,TModel > ();
```

my adapter recieves data from a webservice, this data i wil store in a list of TModel items
The view only show items of UiModel, i will do the following mapping en return the data to the view

```
var list = listOfT.Select(tmodel=> Mapper.Map<UiModel>(tmodel)).ToList();
```

when all of the changes are made i give the list back to a different adapter to save the data into the database

in this 'sqlAdapter' i map the items back of type `TModel`, because i also want the address property in my database

```
var list = listOfUi.Select(uimodel=> Mapper.Map<TModel>(uimodel)).ToList();
```

but now i have lost the data of the address property.
must i also pass throug the original list of TModel's?...

Comment: `UiModel` class does not have `Address` property. So when you convert from `TModel` to `UiModel` it is nowhere available. That's why when you convert `UiModel` back to `TModel` you are not getting the `Address` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple different ways you could solve this. The simplest answer would be to modify your UiModel class so that it has an address property. So something like:

```cs
  public class UiModel
    {
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public string Location{get;set;} 
      public string address {get;set;}
    }
```

Automapper works by first trying to match property names. If it doesn't find a match then you have to either modify your class so that it finds a match or write a class that implements the ***IValueResolver*** interface. More on that can be found at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

Comment: I was thinking the same to extend my UiModel class with that property. the reason that i don't put it in there was because my view model has no extra value of the address property. So than i have no extra value that i plit my value from a webservice of DB to the data that is only mentioned for the view and data for backhand check?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that you don't want to add it to your view model because it isn't being used in the UI and would therefore be an extra property?

Comment: I understand that the view is mapped with the property's he found in the TModel. But i recieve from my service also the address property and after the user make some changes i will save the data into the db. But like you explaned it i most also place the address property in the UIModel outherwise i dont have this value anymore when i do a save.